# sIFR v2 overlaping slimbox (and possibly other lightbox tools)

Tags: sifr

Just installed sIFR into the site I am building (a personal portfolio site). When using it on pages with slimbox popups, sIFR overlaps the slimbox and makes it dificult to see the image. I tried applying a high z-index to the items I didn't want overlapped, but that didn't solve anything. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like (since my site is not online yet):

http://users.sephiroth.ws/DemonicGoblin/sifr.png

Is there a way to hide the sIFR when a slimbox link is clicked, or a way to adjust the z-index for a way to it not to be always on top? This happens on the latest version of all major browsers (I couldn't test Safari or Chrome though, even though I doubt it will differ)

I ahvent been able to find any information regarding this subject, so if it has been fixed in the sIFR beta it would be nice to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In sIFR 2 you need to set the `sWmode` parameter to `"opaque"`. This should allow HTML elements to be displayed on top of the Flash movie.

In sIFR 3, the parameter is `wmode`, though you can also use `opaque: true`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much - just saved my day.

I saw that lightbox break - so did I nearly:)!!! 
But what a straight forward answer and solution thanks!! again

The file in mention is:
sifr.js

and put a code like: 
sIFR.replaceElement(named({sSelector:"h1", sFlashSrc: "http://localhost/ddddddd/templates/template/i_font_swf/carbon_std_swf.swf", sCase: "upper", sColor: "#86ca29", **sWmode:"opaque"**, sBgColor:"#fff"}));

I just write it cause took me some time to remember where this setting initially was - when I did the sIFR long ago.